# How can I disable "Copy as HTML" "Paste as HTML" from gnome-terminal context menu?

Tags: gnome-terminal

It appears to have been added between 17.04 and 18.04 and is related to this bug, https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=365121

I tried searching /usr/share/ and /etc/ for a config file but didn't find one
I tried searching google but didn't find any issues.

Thanks in advance for help

Comment: There's no "Paste as HTML". "Copy as HTML" is a new feature. I'm wondering: if you don't like it, what's wrong with simply not invoking this menu entry? You don't go ahead and modify all your software to remove all the features you don't use, don't you? Please clarify: why is it important for you to actually _remove_ it?

Comment: @egmont I accidentally click the option several times a day and I don't ever want to copy or paste as html so I'd prefer it not visible (for the same reason that I might remove a quick launch shortcut that I no longer use, or why I prefer ads to not appear on my screen).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems to be another hard-coded thing. It is just another example of GNOME "user-friendlies".

Some analysis and recommendations are below:

> ```
> $ apt-get source gnome-terminal
> $ cd gnome-terminal-3.28.2/
> $ grep -ir "Copy.*as.*HTML" . --include="*.c" -n
> ./src/terminal-accels.c:141:  ENTRY (N_("Copy as HTML"),        KEY_COPY_HTML,           "copy",         "s", "'html'"   ),
> ./src/terminal-window.c:1782:  g_menu_append (section4, _("Copy as _HTML"), "win.copy::html");
> ```

manually open of `./src/terminal-window.c` shows that corresponding `g_menu_append` is not conditional, so it is included everytime.

Dconf knows only about setting to define/enable/disable keyboard shortcut (toggled in *Preferences→Shortcuts→Edit→Copy as HTML*):

```
$ gsettings list-recursively | grep -i html
org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Keybindings copy-html 'disabled'
```

---

If you don't like that feature, you can try to use another terminal application like MATE Terminal or something else instead:

- Konsole

  [image: Konsole]
- LXTerminal

  [image: LXTerminal]
- MATE Terminal

  [image: MATE Terminal]
- QTerminal

  [image: Qterminal]

Note: in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS the `xfce4-terminal` has the same un-configurable thing.

Comment: Is it possible to build just gnome-terminal from source with the code altered to remove the copy-as-html?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot disable these entries. As in most software, the basic user interface (organization of its menus etc.) is a hard coded integral part of GNOME Terminal, and not configurable (at least not without altering the source code).

Comment: To whoever downvoted my answer: Could you please justify your decision, let me know what's wrong with my answer or what should I improve? Answers should be upvoted or downvoted based on whether they accurately answer the posted question, and not whether you like or dislike the fact that the correct answer is whatever it is (e.g. in this case: not whether you like or dislike that the menus can't be modified).