# Why doesn't MATE respect `x-terminal-emulator`?

Tags: ubuntu-mate, update-alternatives

Running Ubuntu Mate 18.04.1, pretty vanilla install.

Am trying to make Tilix my default terminal emulator.

Have set it as per `update-alternatives`:

```
me@mine:~$ sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator
There are 6 choices for the alternative x-terminal-emulator (providing /usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator).

  Selection    Path                            Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/bin/tilix.wrapper           30        auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/koi8rxterm              20        manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/lxterm                  30        manual mode
  3            /usr/bin/mate-terminal.wrapper   30        manual mode
* 4            /usr/bin/tilix.wrapper           30        manual mode
  5            /usr/bin/uxterm                  20        manual mode
  6            /usr/bin/xterm                   20        manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 
me@mine:~$
```

```
me@mine:~$ sudo update-alternatives --display x-terminal-emulator
[sudo] password for me: 
x-terminal-emulator - manual mode
  link best version is /usr/bin/tilix.wrapper
  link currently points to /usr/bin/tilix.wrapper
  link x-terminal-emulator is /usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator
  slave x-terminal-emulator.1.gz is /usr/share/man/man1/x-terminal-emulator.1.gz
/usr/bin/koi8rxterm - priority 20
  slave x-terminal-emulator.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/koi8rxterm.1.gz
/usr/bin/lxterm - priority 30
  slave x-terminal-emulator.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/lxterm.1.gz
/usr/bin/mate-terminal.wrapper - priority 30
  slave x-terminal-emulator.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/mate-terminal.1.gz
/usr/bin/tilix.wrapper - priority 30
  slave x-terminal-emulator.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/tilix.1.gz
/usr/bin/uxterm - priority 20
  slave x-terminal-emulator.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/uxterm.1.gz
/usr/bin/xterm - priority 20
  slave x-terminal-emulator.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/xterm.1.gz
```

But still, when I hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>, I get MATE Terminal.

What am I missing?

Comment: Since MATE is based on (or the continuation of) gnome 2, I guess there is still a hardcoded list of terminal emulators that are tried to start when using the terminal emulator shortcut, as it was the case some years ago. The easiest workaround is not using that shortcut, but creating a custom one to start tilix and binding Ctrl+Alt+T to that shortcut.

Comment: @danzel Guessing is bad method of solving problems, do not use it next time, it [is not hardcoded](https://github.com/mate-desktop/mate-control-center/blob/b931a8f99fc07cf860819507e18546bb9583a2f1/capplets/default-applications/mate-da-capplet.c#L148). Hardcoded things [are widely used](https://askubuntu.com/a/1079659/66509) in GNOME sHell, not in MATE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The list of default MATE applications is customized by special applet of MATE Control Center.
It is named *Preffered Applications*.

You have to start it with `mate-default-applications-properties` and then set needed *Terminal Emulator* on the *System* tab:

[image: MATE Control Center → Preffered Applications]

and it will open when you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.

---

Note: if we read source code of this component, then we can see that terminal alternatives are enumerated by their desktop-files and not by update-alternatives functionality - see [this code fragment](https://github.com/mate-desktop/mate-control-center/blob/ad16bc21a6eec19d980f68ada38cb79ed5c750a5/capplets/default-applications/mate-da-capplet.c#L607) about desktop file.

Comment: This solved it perfectly. Thank you!